# How to keep apostrophes when creating bigrams in R?

Tags: r, text, text-analysis

I have an existing code used to create a table of all the bigrams in a document, but it removes the apostrophes. How can I adjust this code to treat words like 'I've' as a single term?

```
 text1 = scan(file.choose(), what="character",sep="\n")
 text1 <- tolower(text1)
 tokens <- unlist(strsplit(text1, "[^a-z]+"))
 tokens <- mytable[tokens != ""]
 tokens2 <- c(tokens[-1], ".")
 bigrams <- paste(tokens, tokens2)
 freq <- sort(table(bigrams), decreasing=T)
 write.csv(file = "bigram count.csv" , x=freq, row.names = FALSE)
```

For example, the phrase "I've had fun" would output 'i've had' and 'had fun'

Answer (score 0):

You can use a package such as 'tm' o 'ngram'. For example using ngram to get a data.frame with the bigrams and it's frequency.

```
require(ngram)
TMP <-  "I've had fun tonight" 
TMP1 <- ngram(str = TMP,n = 2)
TMP2 <- as.data.frame(get.phrasetable(TMP1))
TMP2

        ngrams freq      prop
1     had fun     1 0.3333333
2    I've had     1 0.3333333
3 fun tonight     1 0.3333333
```